# My NodeJS server crashes after 6 Axios post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have created an application with a Front End in ReactJS and a Back End in NodeJS.
What I'm doing is to make the Front End communicate with the Back End each time a letter is typed in an input.
It works fine (I can see in my NodeJS console every letter I'm typing), but after 6 hits on keyboard in this input, my NodeJS server crashes, and it seems not responding (I don't have an error).

I have tried to search if it wasn't a problem with Axios, because I tought it doesn't disconnects once the post query is done, but I didn't find anything about this.

I precise I'm new to React and Node, so I might skipped something.

in App.js

```
//This is the React Part

handleAttachmentToTask = async (event) =>{

        let self = this;

        const target = event.target;
        const keystone = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        const postman = {kSent: keystone};

        axios.post('/api/sandbox',{postman})
          .then(response => {
            //self.setState({keystone:response.data});
            console.log(response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }
```

In server.js

```
//This is the NodeJS part

app.post('/api/sandbox', function(req, res){

    var hit = req.body.postman.kSent;
    console.log(hit);

});
```

I just wanted to see the keyboard hits on my NodeJS console, but at the moment, it crashes after 6 letters as I mentionned.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is not sending the response back to the client. Try to send a response.
Try to change your server code.

```
app.post('/api/sandbox', function(req, res){
    var hit = req.body.postman.kSent;
    console.log(hit);
    res.send(200); // Try to send response back to user 
});
```

Comment: That was really useful, thank you mate. I didn't figured out that I didn't send anything in return to the user.